# How to execute a PHP script asynchronously using Ajax on button click?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

A simple question which I have tried to resolve for a dozen of hours and am still stuck. I am fairly new to PHP/Javascript, so it may seem a bit stupid, but I can't do that on my own. Sorry for my English, it's not my native.

I have a local web server, MySQL database and a form named index.php, which is displayed in my Chrome tab when the server is running. There is a button on the form, which is supposed to insert some info in the database asynchronously, i.e. without page reloading. Google says that in order to do so, I have to use Ajax. So I do the following:

1) I place an Ajax function on the "onClick" event of the button placed on the form;

2) I place the PHP "insertion script" into the "Submit" function, which I place either in index.php, or separate file submit.php, which contains only the "insertion script";

3) And when I click the button, nothing happens. Literally nothing. But, if I place some JavaScript operator into the Ajax function itself (for example, a simple "alert("something")"), it works, and the alert is displayed in the browser.

So, the goal is: use some Ajax function to execute a PHP script which has to be placed somewhere and should be called with Ajax, and to be executed without page reloading. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code. We cannot work with a list of things you say you have done. Please read this topic first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can post your code

Comment: it seems your PHP script `submit.php` has some problem. check the log and trace out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving the hint how to do it.Because i don't know which scenario your using this.you can change the code based on your requirement

### html

```
<form id="form-search" method="post" action="<?php echo 
  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input type="email" name="email" type="email" id="email" required/>

 <input type="submit" value="submit" id="save" class="submit" />
```

### this ajax method

//make sure you have to load the jquery library here

```
 $(document).on('click','#save',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  var data = $("#form-search").serialize();
  $.ajax({
         data: data,
         type: "post",
         url: "insert.php",
         success: function(data){
              alert("Data Save: " + data);
         }
});
 });
```

### Insert.php

```
<?php 
    if($_POST['email']!=""))
    {
    //make create connection variable here
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO tablename (email) VALUES ('$email')";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($result){
    echo "You have been successfully inserted.";
    }else{
        echo "not inserted";
    }
   }
    ?>
```